# How to successfully utilize Queue.join() with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, queue

I am trying to learn the multiprocessing library in Python but I cannot get my code to work with `queue.Queue`. Simply put, I have no idea where to put the `queue.Queue.join()` method in my code. Does it go IN the while loop or outside of it? If it goes outside of the while loop, do I write `while q.not_empty`? Why would I use `q.not_empty` when it the docs it is explicitly mentioned to use `join()`?

Here is my code. I am expecting my 4 cores, simultaneously to return the amount of prime numbers computed by my function, 2 times per core for the total amount of 8 computations. The prime computing functions works without problem.

```
import queue
def main():
q = queue.Queue()
[q.put((compute_primes, (1, 30000))) for _ in range(8)]
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    while q.not_empty:
        result = q.get()
        function = pool.apply_async(result[0], args=(result[1][0], result[1][1]))
        function.get()
    q.join()
```

With the code above, I break out of the loop if the queue is empty. But this is supposed to be unrealiable and why would I need `q.join()` afterwards?

With the code below, I can't break out of the loop. Changes are `while True` and position of `q.join()`

```
def main():
q = queue.Queue()
[q.put((compute_primes, (1, 30000))) for _ in range(8)]
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    while True:
        result = q.get()
        function = pool.apply_async(result[0], args=(result[1][0], result[1][1]))
        function.get()
        q.join()
```

Where should I put `q.join`?

P.S. This code also does not parrallelise the tasks effectively, it essentially computes the functions one by one and I cannot understand why, but this is a different problem.

P.S. 2

Code for prime function

```
def compute_primes(start, end):
start_time = time.time()
primes = []
for number in range(start, end + 1):
    flag = True
    for i in range(2, number):
        if (number % i) == 0:
            flag = False
            break
    if flag:
        primes.append(number)
end_time = time.time()
print(f"Time taken: {end_time - start_time}\n"
      f"Amount primes: {len(primes)}")
return primes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Queues and Pools

> Running one at a time... separate problem.

Actually, this is part of the same problem.  All this implies that you are *not*
using a multiprocessing pool managed by `Pool`.  What you do at the moment is to
put all your tasks in a queue, get them straight back out again, and then
process them one at a time using a pool, which only ever gets one task at a
time.  These two paradigms are mutually exclusive: if you want to use a pool to
do the work for you, you don't need queue; if you need to handle the queue
yourself, you probably don't want to use `pool`.

#### Pool

`multiprocessing.Pool` and accompanying methods spawn the right number of worker
processes, serialise your function to them, and then set up a queue internally
and handle sending tasks and getting results.  This is much easier than doing it
manually, and is normally the right way to go about things:

When you use pool, you do something like this:

```py
results = pool.map(compute_primes, [(0,100_000) for _ in range(8)])
```

Which will block for you until all the pool has finished, or:

```py
results = pool.map_async(compute_primes, [(0, 100_000) for _ in range(8)])
results.wait() # wait
```

unless you plan to process the results as they come in, in which case you don't
use `results.wait()` at all:

```py
for _ in range(8):
    result = results.get()
    do_stuff(result)
```

You do use `pool.join()` or `pool.close()` just to make sure the *pool* is shut
down gracefully, but this has nothing to do with getting your results.

#### Your examples

Your first example works, because you do this:

- put tasks in a queue
- get them out one by one and process them
- join an empty queue -> leave immediately

Your second example fails, because you do this:

- put tasks in a queue
- get one task out
- wait for queue to be empty or done -> blocks indefinitely

In this case, you don't *want* a queue at all.

#### Using Queue manually

Aside: where are you getting your `Queue` from?  `multiprocessing.Queue` is not
joinable; you need `multiprocessing.JoinableQueue`.  `threading.Queue` should
not be used with `multiprocessing`.  `queue.Queue`, likewise, should not be used
with `multiprocessing.

When do you use a task queue?  When you *don't* just want to apply a bunch of
arguments to a bunch of functions.  Perhaps you want to use a custom class.
Perhaps you want to do something funny.  Perhaps you want to do some things with
one type of argument, but something else if the argument is of a certain kind,
and code is better organised this way.  In these cases subclassing `Process` (or
`Thread` for multithreading) yourself may be clearer and cleaner.  None of that
seems to apply in this case.

##### Using `join` with queues

`.join()` is for *task* queues.  It blocks until every task in the queue has
been marked as done.  This is handy for when you want to offload some processing
to a bunch of processes, but wait for them before you do anything.  so you
normally do something like:

```py
tasks = JoinableQueue()
for t in qs:
    tasks.put(t)
start_multiprocessing() # dummy fn
tasks.join() # wait for everything to be done
```

However in this case you don't do that, or want to do it.

Comment: From queue.Queue, will update answer.

Comment: @NikolaKapralov I've edited the answer to make it clear what's going wrong at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, in short, Pool was the wrong way to go about it at the first place. This also nicely answers my second question as to why when substituting queue.Queue for a python list, it seems to work flawlessly. If I have understood correctly, Pool is for automatised tasks where my workers will autonomously take items from the list and I suppose Processes are to be used with queue.Queue where every process is to be handled a Queue item manually. Am i correct?

Comment: I have refactored the answer to make it clear that here you don't want to use queues at all

Answer (score 1):

I prefer not to specify an argument to the Pool constructor unless, for some reason, I want very few concurrent processes. By constructing Pool without an argument, the number of potential concurrent processes will vary from computer to computer depending on its CPU architecture. Here's how I would implement your task (assuming I understand your use-case completely):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


def genPrime():  # prime number generator
    D = {}
    q = 2
    while True:
        if q not in D:
            yield q
            D[q * q] = [q]
        else:
            for p in D[q]:
                D.setdefault(p + q, []).append(p)
            del D[q]
        q += 1


def compute_primes(n):
    g = genPrime()
    return [next(g) for _ in range(n)]


NCOMPUTATIONS = 8
NPRIMES = 30_000


def main():
    with Pool() as pool:
        ar = []
        for _ in range(NCOMPUTATIONS):
            ar.append(pool.apply_async(compute_primes, [NPRIMES]))
        for _ar in ar:
            result = _ar.get() # waits for process to terminate and get its return value
            assert len(result) == NPRIMES


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[ Please note that I am not the author of the genPrime function ]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Actually, I have a version of my code which written the same way as yours and it works. But I was left with the impression that Pool workers pick tasks from ar which I imagined to be a Queue which now I understand is not the case. Since I thought it was a queue, I decided to try and do it the 'proper way' and after a bit of searching, came to the conclusion that queue.Queue with get() and join() were the way to go. Thank you for mentioning the CPU counts of Pool as well.

Comment: Queues are useful for multithreading so with multiprocessing. Take a look at multiprocessing.Value() for a mechanism for sharing data between subprocesses. It uses shared memory "under the covers".